# starting mongo with service

Tags: mongodb, docker, service

Running mongodb in docker container on raspbian.
If i run "`service mongodb status`" in container, it says mongodb is not running.
But if i look at `ps aux` it shows the process to be running.
This is from the log

```
Tue Feb 20 02:34:08.166 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 127.0.0.1:27017
Tue Feb 20 02:34:08.166 [websvr] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 127.0.0.1:28017
Tue Feb 20 02:34:08.166 [initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in use
Tue Feb 20 02:34:08.166 [websvr] ERROR:   addr already in use
Tue Feb 20 02:34:08.166 [initandlisten] now exiting
```

`service mongodb start` fails

What is going on with the service?

Comment: Are the logs from inside the container? Are you doing `ps aux` on the host or inside the container?

Comment: By your description it looks as if you already have a MongoDB instance running. I guess you have a native mongodb on your host machine already up and you're trying to start a mongodb container. Try to run your container mapping to a different port `-p 27018:27017`

Comment: @VikramHosakote its inside the container

Comment: @MarcNuri i stopped the mongo instance on the host. It looks like it some problem the service to talking to the daemon

Comment: Are you running a public image or did you implement the image yourself? Usually when running processes such as databases that usually run as services in regular servers, in docker images they are started as attached processes instead of services so that any exit code will stop the container and logs propagate into docker logs.

Comment: i am using a public image `joaquindlz/rpi-docker-lamp:latest`

Comment: @MarcNuri shall i close this question?